# Streaming Real-time data with react and chartjs-plugin-streaming paused

Tags: reactjs, graph, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

When passed like this

> Error: "realtime" is not a registered scale

Refresh function:

```
onRefresh=(chart) =>{
        var now = Date.now();
         chart.data.datasets[0].data.push({
            x: now,
            y: this.state.realdata.sitting
          });
      }
```

Component:

```
                <Line
                  data={{
                    datasets: [
                      {
                        label: "Customers",
                        borderColor: "rgb(54,162, 235)",
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(54,162, 235, 0.5)",
                        lineTension: 0,
                        borderDash: [8, 4],
                        data: this.state.livePeopleSitting,
                      },
                    ],
                  }}
                  options={{
                    scales: {
                      x: {
                          type: "realtime",
                          realtime: {
                            onRefresh: this.onRefresh,
                            delay: 4000,
                            duration: 160000,
                            refresh: 3000,
                          },
                        },
                      y: {
                        title: {
                          display: true,
                          text: "people seated",
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  }}
                />
```

After passing scales as

```
x: [{
...
}]
```

instead of

```
x: {
...
}
```

I stops getting an error, but it doesn't show the x axis at all,
although object form is the latest [chart.js 3.0.0](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.3.0/getting-started/v3-migration.html#scales)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason chart.js doesn't throw an error anymore with array is because chart.js ignores those options.

As stated in the documentation [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc) you will need to import and register everything you use. By default react chartjs import and registers everything from chart.js itself but it can't auto register any plugin things since it doesn't know you are using them.

So to solve the issue you will also need to register the scale like so:
`import { StreamingPlugin, RealtimeScale } from 'chartjs-plugin-streaming';`. After that you can register it like so: `Chart.register(StreamingPlugin, RealtimeScale);`

Comment: It says "Attempted import error: 'RealtimeScale' is not exported from 'chartjs-plugin-streaming' "

Comment: Are you using version 2 (latest) of chart.js streaming because you need that one for v3, the other ones are for v2

Comment: I am using     "chart.js": "^3.5.0",    "chartjs-adapter-luxon": "^1.0.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-streaming": "^2.0.0",

Comment: Both `import { StreamingPlugin, RealtimeScale } from 'chartjs-plugin-streaming';` and registering those and `import ChartStreaming from "chartjs-plugin-streaming";` and registering that work as you can see in this code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-ardinghelli-wk15h?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:289-343. You can uncomment either of the imports and it keeps working

Comment: Found it, i was not registering chartstreaming after registering it works now "Chart.register(ChartStreaming);"
Thank You

Comment: @FahadTahir the correct spelling is RealTimeScale